# Parse String with Interval using Regex

Tags: c#

I have the following regex:

```
String pattern = @"^(?<Negate>!*)\[(?<Value>.+?;.+?)\]$";
```

To parse Strings as "[2;8]" and "![2;8]". So I have:

```
Match match = Regex.Match("[2;8]", pattern);

if (match.Success) {

  String[] values = match.Groups["Value"].Value.Split(';');

  String minimum = values[0];
  String maximum = values[1];

  Boolean negate = match.Groups["Negate"].Value.Length % 2 != 0;            

}
```

The problem is that my Regex does not match "[;8]" or "[2;]".

How can I change this code so I can parse intervals with Min and Max, only Min or only Max?

Comment: What does the `!` in front mean? Do you have an exhaustive list of the input format?

Comment: The ! in front means I want to negate the interval ... just an extra piece of information

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a complex input so I think Regex may not be an efficient solution. You could easily use a combination of `string.Split` and `IndexOf` to achieve same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your test case, I think you may get better efficiency using a combination of `string.Split` and `IndexOf`. i.e.

```
string input = "[2;8]";
bool negate = false;
if(input[0] == '!'){
    negate = true;
    input = input.Substring(1);
}

string[] values = input.Split(';');
string minimum = values[0];
string maximum = values[1];
```

However, a simple modification of your original pattern will do the trick.

```
String pattern = @"^(?<Negate>!*)\[(?<Value>.*?;.*?)\]$";
```

The major problem here is that the usage of '+?' requires that there must be a single occurrence of the value while '*?' means 0 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect

You are saying .+? for the value. This means anything 1 or more with the ? means there or not.

It should be something like this:

```
^(?<Negate>!?)\[(?<Minimum>.*);(?<Maximum>.*)\]$
```

replaced the +? with * which means 0 or more of anything on both sides

Here's a c# code doing what you need to do:

```
var pattern = @"^(?<Negate>!?)\[(?<Minimum>.*);(?<Maximum>.*)\]$";

var match = Regex.Match("[2;8]", pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    var min = match.Groups["Minimum"].Value;
    var max = match.Groups["Maximum"].Value;
    var negate = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Negate"].Value);

     Console.WriteLine("Min = {0} - Max = {1} - Negative = {2}",min,max,negate);
}
```

I suggest you download [The regex coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/). It can help you test your regex

Edit:
changed the value for min/max

Comment: Would be possible instead of having <Value> in the Regex to have <Minimum> and  <Maximum> and get them directly?